# NSValue may not respond to... warning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, warnings, cmtime

I'm getting a warning in XCode which says `NSValue may not respond to +valueWithCMTime:'` but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. In my header file, I have this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreMedia/CoreMedia.h>

...
-(void)displayTime:(CMTime)time;
```

and in my implementation file, I have this:

```
-(void)displayTime:(CMTime)time
{
     //This line has the warning
     [mutableArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]];
}
```

I've used the above line elsewhere in another class and there's no warning, so what could be missing from this one? Is it something to do with the way the method is set up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've probably forgotten to import the AVFoundation headers.

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Comment: That was it, thanks. I had `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` because I thought the docs were referring to that.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone class `NSValue` has no `valueWithCMTime`.

Check out the online [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSValue_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

It is added by AVFoundation framework, as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/NSValue_AVFoundation_Additions/Reference/Reference.html).

Added the corresponding header inclusion :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an NSMutableArray.... because you need an NSValue